# Inclusion of generic views in django - how to do it the right way?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have TemplateView's for the home and about pages of a website for an event organizer. Now I want to include a template with a list of the next three events in both templates like this:

```
{% include "next-events.html"%}
```

Since this template should be included in both pages, I thought about writing a ListView only for the next events and including it in my home and about views.

```
class NextEventsView(ListView):
    """ a preview of the next events """
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('date')[:3]
    context_object_name = 'next_events'

class HomePageView(TemplateView, NextEventsView):
    template_name = "home/home.html"

class AboutPageView(TemplateView, NextEventsView):
    template_name = "home/about.html"
```

But I have not fully understood how the ListView generic view get's its object_list. If I include like this, i get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

That can be resolved by adding object_list to the HomePageView, but that can not be the right solution.

Can anybody explain, how to do such an inclusion the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have listed the superclasses the wrong way round; some of the methods in ListView are more specific than the ones in TemplateView, but because the latter is listed first the methods will be found there instead.

However there doesn't seem to be any need to inherit from TemplateView at all. ListView already does, and allows you to set a template_name anyway. Just drop the TemplateView from the inheritance.